# Rails Paperclip Attachment not saving because polymorphic id not assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am brand new here. I have been fighting with a rails app for hours now and need an answer. I have searched and tried many suggestions related to what I am trying to accomplish, but to no avail. I got the paperclip gem running for my rails app yesterday, and it was a breeze to add an attachment to a single model. However, I defined an agnostic, polymorphic attachments table to hold attached files for all models that need this functionality.

My issue is that I cannot get the attached file to save through nested parameters. All my parameters are accepted, but the db rolls back and doesn't save (using guard). Message is: 'attachments.attachable_id'=>'can't be blank'. I need this to be the foreign key of the related table, and this has to be saved along with the attachment_type. Here's what I have:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @report = Report.new
  @report.attachments.build(attachable_id: @report.id)
end

def create
  @report = Report.new(params)
  @report.attachments.build                   

  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.save
      format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @report, status: :created, location: @report }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def report_params
  params.require(:report).permit(:filing_year, :filing_number, :order_number, :location, :environmental_review,:biological_review, :cultural_review, :date_received, :status, attachments_attributes: [:id, :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :attachment])
  end
end
```

And for the models:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  validates :attachable_id, :attachable_type, presence: true
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :attachment

  Paperclip.interpolates :attached_to do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.attachable.class.to_s.downcase
  end

  has_attached_file :attachment,
                :url => "/attachments/:id/:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:attached_to/:id/:basename.:extension",
                :default_url => "/attachments/original/no-file.txt"

end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :environmental_review
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

  validates :order_number, presence: true
  .
  .
  .
end
```

And view (in slim):

```
.report
  = form_for @report do |f|
    .
    .
    .
    = f.fields_for :attachments do |a|
      = a.file_field   :attachment
    .
    .
    .
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one in your `create` method you call `@reports.attachments.build` again, but don't set the `assignable_id`, you need to do that.  The other thing you can do is add a hidden form field that has the name `attachable_id`.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work even when I tried that both ways (re-build or hidden form field). The best workaround seemed to be just restructuring and putting in a separate controller for attachment uploads. Thanks.